# Save extra fields in user registration by dj_rest_auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I've been on dj_rest_auth on this project. Trying to add extra fields to the custom user model but it only saves the email and password. I think I have everything right but nothings working.

Heres my user model

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, allow_blank=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, allow_blank=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30, allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')
    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.phone = self.data.get('phone')
        user.first_name = self.data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = self.data.get('last_name')
        user.save()
        return user
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
}

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

and finally in my urls.py

```
path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
```

From postman I send this post request

```
{
    "email": "ahsan44411@gmail.com",
    "password": "ahsan44411",
    "password2": "ahsan44411",
    "first_name": "ahsan",
    "last_name": "mukhtar",
    "phone": "64763868"
}
```

It only saves the email address, phone, first_name, last_name are not saved.
I have searched read nearly every problem on stackoverflow, without any luck, now I am posting here, please inform me if problem is not clear.

Comment: create `UserSerializer` by inheriting from the `dj_rest_auth`'s serializer class

Comment: @JPG you were right answer the question so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create` function to save user data like this. Hope this answer will help you to solve your problem.

```
    def create(self, data):
        u = User(username=data["username"], email=data["email"],phone=data["phone"], first_name=data["first_name"],last_name=data["first_name"])
        u.set_password(data["password"])
        u.save()
        return u
```